# Stay SOLID and DRY with coroutines and functions as methods in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dry, solid-principles

I have that Code example:

```
from time import sleep
import asyncio

class bird:

    def __init__(self, sleeptime=1):
        self.var = sleeptime

    def wait_meep(self):
        sleep(self.var)
        print("Meep")

    def do_sth(self):
        print("Dop Dop Do do ...")


class bird_async:

    def __init__(self, sleeptime=1):
        self.var = sleeptime

    async def wait_meep(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(self.var)
        print("Meep")

    def do_sth(self):
        print("Dop Dop Do do ...")
```

As you can see, both clients are mostly identical and shall contain the same name (so that everyone knows what to expect). Now I want to be [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and write `bird_async(bird)`. Because every extension in `bird` shall be used in `bird_async` as well. This is possible, but my coworker says, it is not SOLID, because I have overwritten `wait_meep`. Now I am looking for different soultions and found abstract classes.
What I don't know is, if creating an abstract class `birdBase(ABC)` would be SOLID as well. I would overwrite there as well, because first it was a function and then a couroutine, or am I wrong here?

What could be a SOLID and DRY solution to get those both classes together, without renaming the methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The DRY solution is some kind of subclassing as you already did.

I think a "SOLID" solution is very hard to achieve under your condition. Fact is, you have two functions `wait_meep`, which have actually different signature and semantics. Namely, the first one blocks for the sleep interval, which can be arbitrary long. The second one OTOH is async, i.e. needs special calling semantics and runs concurrently.

A somewhat comparable case is the `Queue` class from the standard library. There you have `get` and `get_nowait` methods which do the same, in different ways. Second example could be `__iter__` and `__aiter__` methods.

So I think the only "correct" solution would be renaming one of the methods. Which would have the side effect that you could write it all as one class, i.e. reduce number of moving parts.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

You have two classes with duplicate code that could make use of inheritance, but don't want to overwrite wait_meep. Furthermore, there is hardcoded text in `wait_meep` and `do_sth` that is unable to be customized.

## Solution

Consider the following to make your code more SOLID and DRY:

```
from time import sleep
import asyncio

class Bird:
    DEFAULT_WAIT_MEEP_TEXT = "Meep"
    DEFAULT_DO_STH_TEXT = "Dop Dop Do do ..."

    def __init__(self, sleeptime=1):
        self.sleeptime = sleeptime

    def wait_meep(self, text=DEFAULT_WAIT_MEEP_TEXT):
        sleep(self.sleeptime)
        print(text)
        
    def do_sth(self, text=DEFAULT_DO_STH_TEXT):
        print(text)


class BirdAsync(Bird):
    async def wait_meep_async(self, text=DEFAULT_WAIT_MEEP_TEXT):
        await asyncio.sleep(self.var)
        print(text)
```

## Notes

The idea here is to create a specific method to execute async (DRY) and ensure that hardcoded defaults are instead passed in args (Open-Closed principle). Of course this can all be done in the original Bird class without need for a BirdAsync class

Comment: The suggested implementation doesn't invoke `sleep(..)` in `BirdAsync`'s `wait_meep_async(..)` asynchronously - it should have invoked `await asyncio.sleep(..)`.

Comment: @Yoel sorry, fixed.